# PI controller design for zeta converter

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I tried to design a PI controller for this zeta converter... but was unsuccessful in doing so.[image: This is the schematic I made in Simulink.]

I wanted to get a constant dc output but got the following waveform. [image: The output voltage and current waveform.]

How to design this PI controller?
Zeta converter is a fourth-order system and his hard to design a controller.

My design of the components are...
L1 = 1.34e-03H, L2 = 1.34e-03H, C1 = 223-06F, C2 = 1.5e-06F, Load resistance = 5.6 ohms, Source volage = 240 V(rms).

Comment: set the I-gain to zero and only use P-gain.  Does the model work (be it with a steady-state error). Basically it looks like the bandwidth of the controller is too low for the plants response

Comment: Are we talking about [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt372/slyt372.pdf) kind of converter?